# Swift: 360 image with Device Motion

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I’m trying to make an iOS app for viewing 360 degrees images on Google Cardboard (or any other VR glasses) and i’m kinda stuck. What I want is the same thing as the app Round.me (https://round.me/tour/19890/view) does, using Device Motion.

I don’t have much experience with Swift, so I’m trying to figure it out what library should I use. I tried to move the UIView changing the offset, but with no success.

Anyone can give me a tip or recommendation on where should I start and what should I use?

Comment: Hey, Did you find the solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this the Panorama library. It rotates 360 images manually, but it also has VR capabilities
I didn't test its VR capacity, but manual scroll seems to work perfectly, so it should be a good start for you. It's written in Objective-C, but installing it with CocoaPods, it should work. For me though, I had to edit the library and add #import `<GLKit/GLKit.h>` in PanoramaView.h file.
Also go to Link Binary with Libraries and add these libraries

[image: Link Binary with Libraries]

https://github.com/robbykraft/Panorama.